Гиперссылка на страницу в таблице jspdf
Формирую pdf файл библиотекой jspdf


doc.autoTable({
  html: '.table',
  theme: 'grid',
  styles: {
    //font: 'PTSans',
    fontSize: 12,
    halign: 'center',
    minCellHeight: 13
  },
  startY: 75,
  useCss: boolean = true,
  tableWidth: 143,
});



'
Мне нужно что бы в одной колонке были гиперссылки на другие страницы pdf. То есть в таблице например 10 строчек и нужно что бы в каждой ячейка с именем вела на другую страницу. Как это можно сделать?

Сделал ссылку белым цветом и теперь она есть в колонке и всё работает
doc.autoTable({
    head: [['Name', 'Country','Age']],
    body: mergedData,
    theme: 'grid',
    styles: {
      font: 'Roboto', 
      fontSize: 12,
      minCellHeight: 15, halign: 'center'
    },
    didDrawCell: (data) => {
        if (data.column.dataKey === 0 && data.cell.section === "body") {
            if (data.row.raw[0] !== '') {
                const x = data.cell.x;
                const y = data.cell.y + 5;
                const textWidth = doc.getTextWidth(data.row.raw[0].content);
                const xLink = x + textWidth + 28;
                doc.setTextColor(255,255,255); 
                doc.textWithLink('Текст', x, y, { url: '#page=' + (i + 1) }); 
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
});

